# How to create table in admin site members without reference

Tags: python, django

How to create table in admin site members without reference

```
class Mas_Members(models.Model):
    ID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, serialize=True)
    MemberName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    RegMethod = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=C_RegMethod)
    RegID = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    DeviceOS = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=C_DeviceOS)
    DeviceID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    NotiID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ImageFile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    CountryCode = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    LangCode = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    BirthYear = models.DateField()
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=C_Gender)
    RegisterDate = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    CurLatLocation = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    CurLongLocation = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    LastUpdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

[image]